# Log informations from typeahead search input

Tags: javascript, meteor, typeahead.js

I created a typeahead search field in my meteor app using `sergeyt:typeahead`.

Now I want to log all search requests to know which informations are missing in my database. The thing is, that the users maybe won't press enter. Because of the typeahead-function the user will type some characters and if there is no result, they maybe abort typing. Some of the users will delete the input to try another keyword. I would like to get those informations, if it is technically possible.

So first of all I have to check how many results typeahead gives me, but I don't know where to get this information.

This is my code so far:

```
Template.search.helpers({
    searchData: function() {
        return [
            {
                name: 'cat1',
                valueKey: 'title',
                displayKey: 'title',
                header: '<h3 class="category-name">Category 1</h3>',
                template: 'searchResults',
                local: function() { return Collection.find().fetch(); }
            }
        ]
    },
    selected: function(event, suggestion) {
        if (Router.routes[suggestion.type] === void 0) {
            console.warn('Route not found');
            return;
        }
        else Router.go(suggestion.type, { _id : suggestion.id });
    }
});
```

I would start with a event for that template:

```
Template.search.events({
    'submit form': function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newElement = template.firstNode.children[0][1].value;
        Log.insert({ title: newElement, missing: true });
    },
    'keyup input': function(event, template) {
        var keyword = event.target.value;
        Log.insert({ title: keyword });
    }
});
```

1. submit-event: So if the user presses enter, the keyword will be saved to the collection. But this is quite bad, because this should just happen if there is no typeahead-result, as the user can select a suggestion and then press the enter key to go for that result, but with my code this would be overwritten...
2. keyup-event: Problem with this is, that every key-event will be tracked. For typing 'just searching', there would be 14 inserts to the collection. That's not what I want. If I'm using the change event, the input has to get a blur and that's also not what I need.

So this seems to me not to be the best way.

Maybe it is possible to use the custom events of typeahead.js, like `typeahead:render`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use underscore's [trottle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) to only save the search string every 500ms or so. This will reduce the number of unique search strings you save while still capturing much of the user's back and forth.

In your case:

```
Template.search.events({
    'submit form': _.throttle(function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newElement = template.firstNode.children[0][1].value;
        Log.insert({ title: newElement, missing: true });
        },500);
    },
    'keyup input': _.throttle(function(event, template) {
        var keyword = event.target.value;
        Log.insert({ title: keyword });
        },500);
    }
});
```

Your requirements are a bit contradictory so this seems a reasonable compromise. You want to capture search strings but not every character that is typed on the way to a search string. If you don't throttle and the user types:

```
f o o d
```

Then normally you would save 4 searches:

1. f
2. fo
3. foo
4. food

Then if they decide to backspace one character you would again save:

1. foo

With throttling, assuming the user types at a fairly normal page you will save two searches:

1. food
2. foo

Since they presumably will think about the results that they got with food, decide they went too far (at least 500ms), then backspace.

Comment: That's a quite good idea, but I still have the problem, that the submit event will overwrite the typeahead-enter-event.

Comment: I would use an `input` event instead. That will handle keyboard events as well as copy/paste. Perhaps in combination with `blur`

Comment: Is it possible to throttle without underscore.js? I'm just asking because underscore.js has a lot of functions, but I don't need them...

Comment: It's 5.7Kb minified and compressed. Odds are you'll use more of those functions over time.